# Map a list of names to Form List or Map in Struts 1.2

Tags: jsp, struts-1

I ll explain my question with an example. In my JSP page, the form has paired input elements to type first name and last name of employees. There can be many employees. I need to map those first and last names with employees to a `List` or any `Collection` in Form bean. The List or any other collection  may have value objects having properties 'firstName','lastName'. Is this possible in struts 1.2 ? if possible, how can I do it ? any sample code or useful links would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How many input fields do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be handled in Struts by using indexed and mapped properties.

See the explanations in the documentation: [Indexed Properties, Mapped Properties, and Indexed Tags](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/indexedprops.html).